# Accessing custom button on vf page

Tags: visualforce, custom-button

I want to access a custom button on my vf page.
The custom button can have any action in the backend.

I want to display the same button on vf page so that if I change the action in backend it should get reflected in my vf page as well.

Thanks
Ray

Comment: I found solution for custom link but not for custom button usage..and there is not much around same. I also thought of using a single page which can be configured to behave dynamically. But that requirement is different so this solution not feasible

Comment: and `apex:detail` doesn't work for you? - that would display the custom button.  You could, I suppose, suppress the whole apex:detail DOM with css display:none and then lift the DOM custom button code out to somewhere else on the VF page using more jQuery manipulation